# How to get value of a path in Firebase Realtime Database security rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So, I have a database node `users` which I want to use a node (`firebaseToken`) in it to check if it is the same user trying to access another path in firebase.

```
{
"rules": {
  
    "users":{
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null && auth.uid == $uid",
      ".write": "auth.uid != null && auth.uid == $uid"

      }
    },
    "Chat": {
      ".write":"root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('firebaseToken').val() === auth.uid",
      ".read":"root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('firebaseToken').val() === auth.uid"
    }
}
```

The focus is on the `chat` which I want to validate by using `users`

Please suggest to me the best way to validate this table using `users`

Comment: What is not working with your rules?

Comment: The read and right rule for chat not reachable. I guess i need to make user rule to be only auth.uid != null. I'm going to try that and see

Comment: Your current rules should work (you maybe need to modify `Chat` by `chat`). Did you try to use the "Rules Playground " simulator in the console?

Comment: I think the problem is this ` ".read": "auth.uid != null && auth.uid == $uid",` on users rule, instead of just ` auth.uid != null`.
I tried it just now and it worked.

Comment: Ok. I will use playground to simulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this  `".read": "auth.uid != null && auth.uid == $uid",` on users rule, instead of just  `auth.uid != null`. I tried it just now and it worked.

Comment: Thanks to share the solution with the community. Please, close the question with the answer that resolved the it. Welcome!